# A query for laravel to fetch percentage from the db rows which are "filled" and not empty

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

How can we get the percentage of how many fields in a row have been filled by a user in the table and also fetch the percentage of relations from other tables rows which parent users has relationship with. Example of tables

**Cars table**

```
id     name     wheels     windshields     seats
1     Hyundai    113           221           16
2       BMW      114           154           
3     Toyota                    2
```

If I try to find percent from above table result should come like:

```
1 = 100% details filled
2 = 80% details filled
3 = 60% details filled
```

Now if I am trying to make relations involved in it

**wheels table**

```
id    wheel_type        price
113     alloy            
114  chrome coated       
115     rims             946
```

After checking up relations percentage of cars table results should be something like:

```
1 = 90% details filled
2 = 60% details filled
3 = 60% details filled
```

What do I have to do in Laravel to get such results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trait to calculate the percentage filled for model attributes

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

trait CalculatesFilledPercentage
{
    public function filled()
    {
        $attributes = collect($this->attributes);

        $totalCount  = $attributes->count();
        $filledCount = 0;

        $attributes->keys()
            ->map(function ($key) use (&$filledCount) {
                !empty($this->{$key}) ? $filledCount++ : $filledCount;
            });

        return ($filledCount / $totalCount) * 100;
    }
}
```

Then for all Car records

```php
Car::all()->mapWithKeys(function($car){
    return [$car->id => "{$car->filled()}% details filled"];
});
```

For relations two scenarios need to be addressed:

- HasOne relationship

  - One related record - relatively easy to calculate filled with parent clubbed
- HasMany relationship

  - Many related records - not easy to club details filled with parent